# Firebase onMessageReceived volley post

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send message (or start service) when I've received message from Firebase. Like that:

```
[...]
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    send_message_via_volley();
}
[...]
```

It's working, when my phone is active, but when screen is off - it's stopping. 
I also tried with PowerManager nad WifiManager to keep connection and CPU alive.
Is there any solution for do that?

Answer (score -1):

Your `onMessageReceived()` will only be called when your applciation would be in the foreground state. Means in the visible state. If your Application is not visible or your app is either in Background or killed than `onMessageReceived()` will not be called.

Comment: So...start service which will work constantly with START_STICKY - service will be waiting for broadcast from RemoteMessage ?

Comment: No if you app is killed or in background, you will receive the data as a notification and when you tap on the notification the activity will be created and you will receive the data from the intent in this activity.

Comment: Many thanks! Now works fine with JSON data  - phone wake's up also in doze mode! Last question - is there any limit of notification with payload? I know only about max size of data (4KB/1024 character)

Comment: @Bushu please accept and up vote the answer so others can get benefit from this answer.